# Pandas using a for loop to insert values into a cell bases off conditional in the row

Tags: python, pandas, e-commerce, data-cleaning

Hi I'm trying to give these items in an eCommerce store the same parent sku so I can migrate over to new eCommerce store.

```
parent  orig_sku    Name
1090    1090    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket
1196    1196     ML Kishigo 1196 Orange Ultra-Cool Mesh Class 2 Safety Vest, 6 Pockets
1195    1195     ML Kishigo 1195 Lime Class 2 Ultra Cool Mesh Safety Vest, 6-Pockets
8210HL  8210HL  Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests 
21027   21027   Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests | SIZE - COLOR| 2XL/3XL - Lime
21025   21025   Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests | SIZE - COLOR| L/XL - Lime
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Medium
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Large
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Xlarge
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 2Xlarge
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 3Xlarge
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 4Xlarge
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 5xlarge
5370    5370    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Medium
5371    5371    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Large
5372    5372    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Xlarge
5373    5373    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 2Xlarge
5374    5374    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 3Xlarge
5375    5375    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 4Xlarge
5376    5376    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 5xXlarge
FR16002F    FR16002F    HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest 
FR16002F-M  FR16002F-M  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| MD
FR16002F-L  FR16002F-L  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| LG
FR16002F-X  FR16002F-X  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| XL
FR16002F-2X FR16002F-2X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 2X
FR16002F-3X FR16002F-3X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 3X
FR16002F-4X FR16002F-4X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 4X
FR16002F-5X FR16002F-5X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 5X
FR16002G    FR16002G    HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest
FR16002G-M  FR16002G-M  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| MD
FR16002G-L  FR16002G-L  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| LG
FR16002G-X  FR16002G-X  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| XL
FR16002G-2X FR16002G-2X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 2X
FR16002G-3X FR16002G-3X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 3X
FR16002G-4X FR16002G-4X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 4X
FR16002G-5X FR16002G-5X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 5X
```

Heres what I've got so far.

```
def copy_parent_sku_to_children(data):

    temp_sku = ''

    for a, b, c, d in zip(data.Name, data.parent, data.PartNumber, range(len(data))):


        if "|" not in a:

            temp_sku = b

        else:
            data.at[d, 'parent'] = temp_sku

    return data
```

df = copy_parent_sku_to_children(df)

and I get this.

```
parent  orig_sku    Name
1090    1090    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket
1196    1196     ML Kishigo 1196 Orange Ultra-Cool Mesh Class 2 Safety Vest, 6 Pockets
1195    1195     ML Kishigo 1195 Lime Class 2 Ultra Cool Mesh Safety Vest, 6-Pockets
8210HL  8210HL  Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests 
8210HL  21027   Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests | SIZE - COLOR| 2XL/3XL - Lime
8210HL  21025   Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests | SIZE - COLOR| L/XL - Lime
8210HL  1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Medium
8210HL  1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Large
8210HL  1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Xlarge
8210HL  1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 2Xlarge
8210HL  1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 3Xlarge
8210HL  1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 4Xlarge
8210HL  1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 5xlarge
8210HL  5370    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Medium
8210HL  5371    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Large
8210HL  5372    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Xlarge
8210HL  5373    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 2Xlarge
8210HL  5374    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 3Xlarge
8210HL  5375    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 4Xlarge
8210HL  5376    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 5xXlarge
FR16002F    FR16002F    HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest 
FR16002F    FR16002F-M  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| MD
FR16002F    FR16002F-L  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| LG
FR16002F    FR16002F-X  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| XL
FR16002F    FR16002F-2X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 2X
FR16002F    FR16002F-3X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 3X
FR16002F    FR16002F-4X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 4X
FR16002F    FR16002F-5X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 5X
FR16002G    FR16002G    HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest
FR16002G    FR16002G-M  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| MD
FR16002G    FR16002G-L  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| LG
FR16002G    FR16002G-X  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| XL
FR16002G    FR16002G-2X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 2X
FR16002G    FR16002G-3X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 3X
FR16002G    FR16002G-4X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 4X
FR16002G    FR16002G-5X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 5X
```

Which is close but I cant have 8210HL repeat.

I need this.

```
parent  orig_sku    Name
1090    1090    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket
1196    1196     ML Kishigo 1196 Orange Ultra-Cool Mesh Class 2 Safety Vest, 6 Pockets
1195    1195     ML Kishigo 1195 Lime Class 2 Ultra Cool Mesh Safety Vest, 6-Pockets
8210HL  8210HL  Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests 
21027   21027   Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests | SIZE - COLOR| 2XL/3XL - Lime
21025   21025   Ergodyne GloWear 8210HL Class 2 Economy Vests | SIZE - COLOR| L/XL - Lime
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Medium
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Large
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Xlarge
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 2Xlarge
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 3Xlarge
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 4Xlarge
1089    1089    ML Kishigo 1089 Economy Lime Green Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 5xlarge
5370    5370    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Medium
5371    5371    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Large
5372    5372    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| Xlarge
5373    5373    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 2Xlarge
5374    5374    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 3Xlarge
5375    5375    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 4Xlarge
5376    5376    ML Kishigo 1090 Economy Orange Class 2 Safety Vest, 1 Pocket| Size| 5xXlarge
FR16002F    FR16002F    HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest 
FR16002F    FR16002F-M  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| MD
FR16002F    FR16002F-L  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| LG
FR16002F    FR16002F-X  HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| XL
FR16002F    FR16002F-2X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 2X
FR16002F    FR16002F-3X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 3X
FR16002F    FR16002F-4X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 4X
FR16002F    FR16002F-5X HiVizGard FR16002F Class 2 FR Orange Mesh Vest | Size| 5X
FR16002G    FR16002G    HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest
FR16002G    FR16002G-M  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| MD
FR16002G    FR16002G-L  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| LG
FR16002G    FR16002G-X  HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| XL
FR16002G    FR16002G-2X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 2X
FR16002G    FR16002G-3X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 3X
FR16002G    FR16002G-4X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 4X
FR16002G    FR16002G-5X HiVizGard FR16002G Class 2 FR Lime Mesh Vest| Size| 5X
```

I was messing around with and and or operator but, without luck.

Comment: Just to be clear you want to normalise the parent sku as follows - cases where we have a sku like this `FR16002G-5X` we want `FR16002G`? In any case you don't need to copy the entire dataframe you can work on a single column e.g `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: do_something(x))`

Comment: that sounds awesome.